# Dagger bound multiple times : Trying to create a fake implementation

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

Hi I'm trying to create a fake presenter of my activity I have my module let's call it Activity1module where I have set all of the presenter, use-case, everything and it works perfect, but when trying to create a screen which uses that exact activity with a fake presenter it says I've bound multiple times that presenter.

What I've did is :

```
@Module
abstract class Activity1Module{
  @Binds
  abstract fun providePresenter(impl: PresenterImpl) : Activity1Contract.Presenter
  .....
}
```

Then I have created a new module FakeActivity1Module and it's like this :

```
@Module(includes = [Activity1Module::class])
abstract class FakeActivity1Module {
   
   @Binds
   abstract fun bindsFakePresenter(impl: FakePresenterImpl): Activity1Contract.Presenter
   .....
}
```

But looks like it doesn't like this way, is there any way to use the fake one instead of the production one without creating `@Named` or touching production code?

Answer (score 0):

Dagger doesn't have any capability to have one module override another's bindings directly. FakeActivity1Module and Activity1Module should include similar bindings but neither should be in the other's `includes` list.

You can, however, extract common bindings to an Activity1CommonModule (named as you'd like) and have both Activity1Module and FakeActivity1Module include that module. That would allow you to avoid repeating yourself as much as possible, at the conceptual cost of some indirection between files.

You can even include that Activity1CommonModule as a nested interface (or abstract or static class) within Activity1Module; you'd still need Activity1Module's `includes` to contain its own `Activity1Module.Activity1CommonModule.class`, but you'd have the benefit of centralizing all of Activity1Module's bindings in a single file, plus the benefit of easily seeing through diffs (git diff, p4 diff, etc) when a binding moves in or out of the common set.

Answer (score 0):

Same class cannot be injected 2 times and it produce `bound multiple times` error. So for the `FakeActivity1Module` instead of create new injection. Try to override `Activity1Module` and apply your changes.

```
class FakeActivity1Module:  Activity1Module {

   overrides fun providePresenter(): Activity1Contract.Presenter = FakePresenterImpl()
}
```

And you use `FakeActivity1Module` into your component for testing and it should work as expected.